# Gnuplot, Multiplot: Mix normal and parametric plot with a single legend box?

Tags: gnuplot

I create overlapping graphs in Gnuplot, because I mix normal and parametric plots (and also pm3d maps and parametric surfaces). This works fine mostly, except for one thing: If both plots have a title, the legends usually overlaps. A typical example looks like this:

```
#legends.gp
set term pngcairo enhanced color linewidth 1.5  dashed dashlength 1.4 rounded
set output "legends.png"

set title "legends test"

set multiplot

# make a box around the legend
set key box

set border 15 lw 1

# fix the margins, this is important to ensure alignment of the plots.
set lmargin at screen 0.15
set rmargin at screen 0.98
set tmargin at screen 0.90
set bmargin at screen 0.15

set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "sin(x)"

set xrange[0:2*pi]
set yrange[-1:1]

set grid x y

# add single tic at 0.62
set xtics add ("x0" 0.62)

# main plot command
plot sin(x) title "sinus"

# turn everything off
set format x ""   #numbers off
set format y ""
set xlabel ""     #label off
set ylabel ""
set border 0      #border off
unset xtics       #tics off
unset ytics
unset grid        #grid off
unset title       #title off

#plot vertical line at 0.62
set parametric
plot 0.62,t ls 2 lw 2 title "parametric Line"
unset parametric

unset multiplot
```

[image: Legends.png]
My question is now, is there a simple, mostly automatic way to create a single legend for multiple plots?

P.S. Sorry, I ended up making the example file more complex than it had to be by showing some more features, that are hopefully helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a **VERY** dirty hack that works for me.  change:

```
plot sin(x) title "sinus"
```

to:

```
plot sin(x) title "sinus",NaN w l ls 2 lt 2 title "parametric line"
```

Then plot the parametric line without a title (e.g. `notitle` instead of `title "parametric line"`).

This works because gnuplot ignores NaN's when plotting -- Essentially the second thing we're plotting above just adds one element to the legend.  I specify the linetype, etc to be the same as your parametric plot linestyle/type so that it shows up properly in the legend.  To my knowledge, this is the only way to do something like this...

Of course, you could just edit it so that both are plotted parametrically and forgo the entire multiplot buisness...

```
set xrange [0:2*pi]
set yrange [-1:1]
set parametric
set trange [-10:10]
plot t,sin(t) title "Hello", 0.62,t title "World"
```

that's probably the "cleaner" solution...(but less fun working with gnuplot "magic")

Comment: I didn't like this answer at first, but I have used the `NaN`-trick now a few times and it works quite well. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

From the gnuplot info manual:

To draw a vertical line from the bottom to the top of the graph at
 x=3, use:
            set arrow from 3, graph 0 to 3, graph 1 nohead